# How to Connect F710 Wireless Gamepad to XBOX 360?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I have Logitech F710 Controller which can input both DIRECT INPUT & X INPUT. But, i dont really know how to connect this controller to my XBOX360 console to play using this controller for XBOX360. PC Works really well, but i dont know how to connect it to XBOX 360.

Comment: Is it supposed to work on the 360?

Answer (score 4):

The Logitech F710 Wireless Gamepad is a PC-only controller. It's not designed to work with the Xbox 360.

Source: [Logitech's F710 Wireless Gamepad product page](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/f710-wireless-gamepad)